# Select all of the following items that might belong in one column of a table

Tags: sql, database

Select all of the following items that might belong in one column of a table:

I choose: a primary key, a foreign key, multiple values.

Which one is wrong?

Comment: This is not a site where someone will do your homework for you. As a minimum you need to show you have made at least some effort to answer the question e.g. give what you think is the right answer and why you think that - and then ask if you are correct

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT * from TABLE_NAME
```

Asterisk Means 'All'

Answer (score 0):

To get all the entries from a column in a table,
`SELECT <Column_Name> FROM Table_Name;`